# Root-finding algorithm for shifted Signum function

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, roots

So a simplified version of my problem is essentially this : I am working with a discrete function of the form $f(x)=\text{sgn}(x-i)$ for a natural number $i$ (where $\text{sgn}(x)$ is $1$ for $x\geq0$ and $-1$ otherwise). I am trying to find $i$, which I know to be in the interval $[a,b]$. Evaluation of $f(x)$ is very expensive, so minimising the number of evaluations is the most important priority. I am currently using the bisection method, but is there a faster way? The size of the interval $i$ is on will typically be at most about $1000$.

Comment: So, for the interval of the length 1000 in worst case scenario you end up doing $\approx 10$ calculations using bisection. You saying that's too much?

Comment: It takes about 3-4 minutes to evaluate $f(x)$, and I have to do a number on smaller intervals because I need the exact value of $i$. For $i=2$ on $[1,10]$ for example we get $[1,10]\to[1,6]\to[1,4]\to[1,3]\to i=2$ worst case, which is $4$ calculations. $\approx 10$ calculations is okay but ideally every less calculation saves a lot of time.